# Get one column from one table with two columns of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine the results in one output where one column is `DepositNo` and the other is `Doc_Type` where any `Doc_Type` equals to `DocType` (vise versa), the `DepositNo` of `DocType` is displayed.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Doc_Type
  FROM Doc_Outgoing_Details
 WHERE (Doc_Type <> 67)
UNION
SELECT DepositNo, DocType AS Doc_Type
  FROM Doc_Outgoing
 WHERE (DocType <> 67)
```

When I execute it, it says:

> UNION must have and equal number of expressions in their target list.

Comment: Can you post more about your table structure? You probably need to JOIN rather than UNION. A UNION must return the same number of columns that have the same name.

Comment: Your first query has one column. The second has two. You can't `UNION` them - each part of the union needs to have the same number of columns.

Comment: Also what is the point of being inconsistent - use `DocType` or `Doc_Type`, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are missing a column on your second `table`. `UNION` must have equal number of `columns`. This should work.

```
SELECT        O AS DepoSitNo, Doc_Type
FROM            Doc_Outgoing_Details
WHERE        (Doc_Type <> 67)
UNION
SELECT        DepositNo, DocType AS Doc_Type
FROM            Doc_Outgoing
WHERE        (DocType <> 67)
```

Answer (score 1):

when You use union you should match all columns and your result sets should have same numbers of columns so you need to generate Doc_Type column in your fist query too :

```
SELECT        Doc_Type,0 as Doc_Type  // or every value 
                                      //that you didn't use in real DOCTYPE
FROM            Doc_Outgoing_Details
WHERE        (Doc_Type <> 67)
UNION
SELECT        DepositNo, DocType AS Doc_Type
FROM            Doc_Outgoing
WHERE        (DocType <> 67)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of columns projected on your `SELECT` statement doesn't match. The first one contains one column and other second one has two. Try adding null value on the first query,

```
SELECT    Doc_Type as DepositNo, NULL Doc_Type
FROM      Doc_Outgoing_Details
WHERE     Doc_Type <> 67
UNION
SELECT    DepositNo, DocType AS Doc_Type
FROM      Doc_Outgoing
WHERE     DocType <> 67
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT d.DepositNo, D.Doctype
FROM Doc_Outgoing d
INNER JOIN Doc_Outgoing_Details do
    ON d.Doctype = do.Doc_type
WHERE (d.DocType <> 67)
```

Comment: Why give me -1? @Arwa A says he only wants rows where where `any Doc_Type equals to DocType (vise versa)`. How does the `UNION` do this?